# How to read CSV file in controller using jQuery ajax of Rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, blob

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where I have to `read CSV file data` and display it but using jQuery ajax.

Now, i did `browse file` then post data using `jQuery ajax` to controller action but get file in `blob format` and get `error`.

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - blob:9a435b68-b8d3-4304-99e1-f1f43955676c

=================== Code =====================

$('input[type=file]').change(function(event) { 

  $("#submit_data").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({url: "/import_data", type: "POST", data: formData,
      success: function(data)
      { 
          alert(345)
      }
    });
  });

================================================
```

Any one have a any other way or solution of it.

Thanks

Comment: if you post a file to the controller (you cant post it somewhere else), you will always be able to read it as a file or as a stream

Comment: Please check code in question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the processData and contentType arguments of $.ajax request to false for the FormData object to be treated correctly and upload the file.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/import_data",
  data: formData,
  processData: false, //<-- important
  contentType: false, //<-- important
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data)
  { 
    alert(345)
  }
});
```